# What is in /dev, /proc and /sys?

Tags: filesystems, mount

After `mount` there are listed some filesystems. I need to know what's in the `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys`. Some examples would be great!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: @dgsleeps the FHS doesn't define the contents of /proc and /sys because they are kernel depended

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `/dev` tree contains [device nodes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/dev.html), which gives [user space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) access to the [device drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) in your OS's running kernel.¹ All POSIX type OSes have a `/dev` tree.

The `/proc` tree originated in System V Unix, where it only gave information about each running process, using a `/proc/$PID/stuff` scheme. [Linux greatly extended that](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html), adding all sorts of information about the running kernel's status. In addition to these read-only information files, Linux's `/proc` also has writable virtual files that can change the state of the running kernel. BSD type OSes generally do not have `/proc` at all, so much of what you find under here is non-portable.

The intended solution for this mess in Linux's `/proc` is [`/sys`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt). Ideally, all the non-process information that got glommed into the `/proc` tree should have moved to `/sys` by now, but historical inertia has kept a lot of stuff in `/proc`. Often there are two ways to effect a change in the running kernel: the old `/proc` way, kept for backwards compatibility, and the new `/sys` way that you're *supposed* to be using now.²

---

**Footnotes:**

1. There are also several `/dev` entries that do not correspond to hardware devices, such as `/dev/null`, `/dev/random`, and `/dev/tty`. These are virtual devices that let user space programs talk to other parts of the kernel besides the running drivers in a device-like fashion.
2. As a rule, `/sys` tends to be more strictly organized than `/proc`, since `/sys` mirrors the internal kernel data structures that manage the system's resources, whereas `/proc` grew organically over many years, and old questionable design decisions can't change now because there are programs using those old interfaces. `/sys` started out with a clearer design, and doesn't have to drag around as much historical baggage as `/proc`.

Comment: Also, they don't keep the sort of files that you should backup. They are dynamically generated. They use special “Magic” file-systems.