# Is /sys content obsolete in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, proc, fhs

EDIT: By obsolete I don't mean bad/unnecessary (I agree with `/proc` being a mess). Modularity is a good thing and I love it. I mean is: information of the system, held (in `/sys`) that is findable somewhere else.

I couldn't really find much information about `/sys` and `/proc`. Besides both of there contents not being part of the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) (because the way they, look like/are build up is kernel version depended)

/sys **doesn't** even have it's own `man` page. `/proc` [has it's own man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and oh boy it has pretty much explanation and still I have some folders and files (for example `/acpi` and `consoles`)
which are not mentioned in it.
`/sys` is pretty new right? And before it existed all of the info that `/sys` gives was part of `/proc` right?

## Question:

Is this still the case?
Can all the info form `/sys` be found on `/proc` in one or another form? That would make a documentation for `/sys` obsolete because it's just an expansion with user friendly design, right? Or is there any system info in `/sys` that isn't in some other form present in `/proc`?

If this is the case where is the place that explains `/sys` to linux amateurs?

Comment: In general `/proc` is for higher level kernel/process stuff whereas `/sys` is for hardware behavior. The hardware entries underneath `/proc` are usually older entries that pre-date `/sys`

Comment: So the only difference between the hardware info provided by both of them is the sorting and displaying?

Comment: The difference is that the `/proc` hardware data/files are older.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/sys` is not obsolete, on the opposite, `/sys` is newer that `/proc` and will grow in the future.

`/proc` (and `procfs`) predates Linux by several years. It was designed to allow access to running processes structures, and nothing else, and especially aimed for debuggers and similar tools. It remains restricted to this goal in current SVR4 based OSes like Solaris. On the other hand, Linux procfs implementors thought it was a good idea to use procfs to also access kernel structures unrelated to processes, thus the mixing of numerical directories directing to processes information and text files and directories given access to kernel statistics, tables and other data. This approach was ported to AIX and is partially emulated on BSDs to ease porting Linux software.

When it became obvious this approach was leading to a mess, `/sys` was created with a better design and some of `/proc` entries moved to it. Unfortunately, a lot of tools have `/proc/something` hardcoded so the most commonly used directory entries under `/proc` are here to stay.

About how to know what kind of information contains a given file under a given path under either `/proc` or `/sys`, documentation, if any, is as you noticed not easy to find. Hopefully, the kernel is open source so the last resort is to look at its code.

See also: [What is the difference between procfs and sysfs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4884/what-is-the-difference-between-procfs-and-sysfs) and [What is in /dev, /proc and /sys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188886/what-is-in-dev-proc-and-sys)

Comment: >moved to it >here to stay.   Sorry I know nothing about this, but: kernel information dosen't have to be in either one or the other, or not? both are virtual filesystems made by it, it can put the same info about for example(what filesystems are available for mounting, what bridges lead to other buses form the dram controller) in /proc and /sys. since I found on both of them, some info about what devices are present in the system. I asked myself Is there any info in /sys that isn't also findable in /proc ?

Comment: Yes, of course there can be redundant paths to the same information. I just checked on a laptop and `/sys` has 46923 files while `/proc` has 1501 ones, excluding of course`/proc/<pid>` so yes, there must be a lot of information available under `/sys` that is not under `/proc`.

Comment: after digging around in /sys a lot I know that most of them if not 4/5th or so are just links that go a few dirs back

Comment: Removing the symlinks reduce the number from 46923 to 44322 on my laptop. But this is not a fair comparison as many /sys entries only give a single statistic/value, which is simpler to handle by programs compared to the /proc usual name/value tables.

Comment: wtf, so many still? well mb. thanks for answering ^^

Comment: btw what did you use to search?

Comment: @Junaga `find /sys ! -type l | wc -l`