# Identify device by its handler

Tags: udev, devices, input

I'm looking for a robust method for identifying a device's type (mouse, keyboard, joystick)
by its input event handler.

There are parameters which cannot be trusted, such as device name/vendor-id etc. since that they are supplied by the device itself.
AFAIK, the input event handler (part of the Linux Input Subsystem) corresponds to a device type.

So how do you *absolutely* know that the device is e.g. a keyboard ?
By matching its input event handler to a known keyboard-event-handler's name.

---

I'm familiar with the file `/proc/bus/input/devices` which provides also several handlers, but it doesn't feel "the right place to look" since that I didn't find any official explanation about this file, and:

> ... BSD type OSes generally do not have /proc at all, so much of what you
>   find under here is non-portable.
>
> The intended solution for this mess in Linux's /proc is /sys. Ideally,
>   all the non-process information that got glommed into the /proc tree
>   should have moved to /sys by now, but historical inertia has kept a
>   lot of stuff in /proc.

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188891/4313).

For example in my system, the event handler for a keyboard is `kbd`.

---

How do I find a device's input event handler without accessing `/proc` ?